# When dealing cards over the internet, is it better to distribute seed values or actual objects?

Tags: java

I am working on a spades game that connects players over the internet, but I don't know how I should distribute the cards to players:

- If I send the seed values for the SecureRandom object used for shuffling to each player, they could theoretically sniff their own traffic for the values and look at the source code to create their own program that deals the cards similarly;
- But if I use the dealer-player's machine to deal the cards and send them to the other players, the dealer could theoretically cheat.

Sending seed values would decrease the amount of data sent over the internet, but sending the actual cards would seem to make it harder to cheat. I've thought about making my own trusted third-party server that the dealer-player would send their seed values to and would send the cards to the other players, but that would require setting up an EC2 instance and I have no idea how to even begin to do that.

Or am I overthinking this a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can have a decentralized card game without cheating.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_poker)

However, you should consider that cheating might not be an issue as long as players aren't competing to be on a leaderboard or anything.

Also, if the dealer sends just the seed out, he can still cheat.

Comment: I figured that the dealer could still cheat if he sent the seed out, but _everyone_ could also cheat if he did so so it would balance out.

Comment: Wait, how does that balance out? What if some users are not tech-savvy enough to use wireshark?

Comment: For the purposes of my problem I was acting under the assumption that every player was both malicious and capable; you are right that this will not be the case in the real world though.

Comment: You don't need to assume that EVERYONE is malicious and capable. Only that there are some such people out there.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the only way to prevent cheating is to have a central, trusted server deal the cards, and notify each user what cards he got. Or is the problem that you don't have a central, trusted server, but rather are making an app available which other users can run as a "dealer"?

If that's the case, I would think the problem is unsolvable even in theory. If someone else runs the server that deals the cards, no matter how you manage it, he could always fudge the seed value to give everyone the cards he wants, or examine the seed value so he can predict all the cards that will come up. Or for that matter, he could intercept the output stream from his server and replace it with whatever cards he wants.

I was briefly thinking that you could send some hash value along with each deal that is associated with the random number generator, so that a program on the receiving end could validate that the hash is consistent with the card sent. Assuming the hash is generated by some secure encryptian algorithm, the dealer could have a hard time changing a card and generating a fake hash code that was consistent with the card he sent. But that would be easy to beat: The dealer could just run the deal program a few hundred times, get a list of valid deals and hash codes, and then pick one of these to send out.

Maybe you could have the players send a token which is factored into the random number generator. But I can't think of an actual algorithm for including such a token that can't be beaten by the dealer system simply repeating whatever calculation is done on the token.

Answer (score 0):

If you send a seed, then any player can find out the cards any other player is holding. Also, the dealer can choose the seed he sends out to be in his favor.

If you send cards from the dealer, then the dealer knows what everyone is holding. Either use a central server, or use some crypto like Nick's answer suggests